# Unmounting and then immediately remounting SMB share as different user fails

Tags: windows, networking, race-condition, smb

I am working on an MFC application that runs on Windows XP SP3.  One of the requirements is that when a user logs into the application, the application must mount several SMB shares hosted on an embedded Linux server using that user's credentials.

The program has a "switch user" feature, which allows a different user to log in without closing the application, terminating the first user's session.  When that happens, the SMB shares must be unmounted and then remounted as the new user.

We do this by calling [`WNetCancelConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) followed immediately by [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  `WNetCancelConnection2` returns `NO_ERROR`, indicating it was successful.  **However, sometimes `WNetAddConnection2` will fail to remount the drive as the new user.**  Using `FormatMessage` to obtain an error string from the return value results in this error message, despite the fact that `WNetCancelConnection2` seemed to succeed:

> > Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Running `net use` from the command prompt does not show an open connection to the SMB share either.

**This failure will not occur if the user never interacts with the mounted drive.  It only occurs if the user has accessed the mounted drive in some way, i.e. the user opened the mounted drive in Windows Explorer.**  Likewise, it does not occur if you quit the application completely and then restart it and log in as a different user.

All of this leads me to believe that there is a race condition where `WNetCancelConnection2` returns before all open handles to the network resource are closed.  My question is **can I make my program block or wait after calling `WNetCancelConnection2` until all those handles are closed, guaranteeing that `WNetAddConnection2` doesn't fail in this way?**  Either a blocking API or a way to busy-wait for the connection to be fully closed would be acceptable.  Either would be preferable to `sleep()` and hope for the best. :-)

Comment: Have you thought of a delay and retry on failure for this? I suspect that you are simply hitting the system too fast.

Comment: @Lazarus, yes, I've considered that solution.  I'd prefer to have the OS tell me when the first connection is fully closed.  If that's not possible, a delay and retry will work in a pinch.

Comment: I have placed this code in a wait/retry loop, as Lazarus suggested.  That solves my problem in the meantime.  I'd still be interested if anyone has a suggestion for a more robust solution.